# listener on UL iterate through li

Tags: javascript, object, iterator

I have the following html:

```
<ul class="collection">
   <li>a
      <a class=" delete-item secondary-content">
         <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>s
      <a class=" delete-item secondary-content">
         <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>w
      <a class=" delete-item secondary-content">
         <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have an onclick listener on the UL (called taskList).  console.log says the element UL (taskList) is an object. Can I iterate through the li's as follows:

```
for (const task in taskList) {
   console.log(task);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `for ... in` will loop over the properties of the object. You could use `for ... of` to loop over the `children`.

```js
const taskList = document.querySelector('ul.collection');
for (const task of taskList.children) {
   console.log(task.outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul class="collection">
   <li>a
      <a class=" delete-item secondary-content">
         <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>s
      <a class=" delete-item secondary-content">
         <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>w
      <a class=" delete-item secondary-content">
         <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when I try for (const task of taskList) {
  console.log(task);
} it says taskList is not iterable.  Why does it say that when it says taskList is an object?

Comment: @DCR We should be iterating over the children (as shown in the snippet): `for (const task of taskList.children) ...`

Comment: @DCR Happy to help.